# passing a name and List of object in feature file in cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I want to pass something like this in feature file in cucumber

```
Feature: Testing different requests on the XLR CD API
Scenario: Check if the student application can be accessed by users
Scenario Outline: Create a new student & verify if the student is added
When I create a new student by providing the information studentcollege <studentcollege> studentList <studentList>
Then I verify that the student with <student> is created
 Examples: 
  | studentcollege                   |  studentList                                                              | 
  | abcd                             | [{student_name": "student1","student_id": "1234"},{student_name": "student1","student_id": "1234"}]  |
```

I have class as

```
Class Student{
     String name;
     String id;
}
```

and step definition file is

```
    @When("^When I create a new student by providing the information studentCollege (.*) studentList (.*)$")
public void generatestudent(String studentOwner, List<Student> listOfstudent) {
    // need to fetch values in here from whatever is given in feature file

}
```

how to pass such values in feature file Example. so that can be retrieved in step definition function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying your question

Comment: @StefanCrain Hoping it is more clear now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using the `@Transform` annotation in the stepdefinition. Also the student list string in the feature file looks like a `Json` string, so easiest to parse using Gson.

Relevant scenario

```
  Scenario Outline: Create a new student & verify if the student is added
    When I create a new student by providing the information studentcollege <studentcollege> studentList <studentList>

    Examples: 
      | studentcollege | studentList                                                                                         |
      | abcd           | [{"student_name": "student111","student_id": "1234"},{"student_name": "student222","student_id": "5678"}] |
```

Stefdefinition class

```
@When("^I create a new student by providing the information studentcollege (.*?) studentList (.*?)$")
public void iCreateANewStudentByProvidingTheInformation(String arg1, @Transform(StudentListTransformer.class)List<Student> arg3) {
    System.out.println(arg1);
    System.out.println(arg3);
}
```

Transformer class

```
public class StudentListTransformer extends Transformer<List<Student>>{

    @Override
    public List<Student> transform(String value) {
        //Sample json -- [{'name': 'student100','id': '1234'},{'name': 'student200','id': '5678'}]

        return new Gson().fromJson(value, ArrayList.class);
    }
}
```

Student dataobject-

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [name=" + name + ", id=" + id + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: what "Transformer" are you using?, there are lots of options but you do not put the imports...

Comment: currently the import needed is io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.Transformer
using "implements" instead of "extends"