# Pass list of integers in cucumber outline scenario

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

I am trying to pass list of integers in cucumber outline scenario

```
Given an API request for <account_id> is made    
And the returned list is in sorted order <placement_detail_ids>

Examples:
  | account_id | placement_detail_ids |
  | 2000       | 1002,1000,1001
  | 2001       | 1004,1003           |
```

I want to take placement detail id values as list in test. How can I do it?

Comment: Which version of cucumber r u using?

Comment: 1.2.5 @Grasshopper

Comment: Use the Transformer annotation. Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49908720/passing-a-name-and-list-of-object-in-feature-file-in-cucumber/49915390#49915390

Comment: U shld look at upgrading cucumber version. Latest one is 4...

Comment: For now I have achieved it taking those numbers as string and splitting them as long array. As these are not object fields and just numbers, I am not sure using Transformer is good practice.

Comment: if anybody looked in here.  @And("^the returned list is in sorted order with \"([^\"]*)\"$")
  public void theReturnedListIsInSortedOrderWithPlacement_detail_ids(String placementIds) throws Throwable { 
    long[] numbers = Arrays.stream(placementIds.split(",")).mapToLong(Long::parseLong).toArray();}

Comment: Transformer can also be used for returning an integer array to the step method. Can u specify why it is not a good practice?

Comment: Sorry my bad I am new to cucumber. never mind. Thanks for your help